# Twitter bootstrap and spans in a control-group

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a simple interface where I've got a series of buttons (checkboxes) which are part of a group.

I would like to split the groups so I can only have 3 per row max.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="control-group">
    <p class="pull-left"><label class="control-label" for="Languages">Lingue</label></p>
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-horizontal" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="Languages_0" name="Languages" checked />
        <label class="btn btn-info btn-small active" for="Languages_0">Italiano</label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="Languages_1" name="Languages" checked />
        <label class="btn btn-info btn-small active" for="Languages_1">Francese</label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="3" id="Languages_2" name="Languages" checked />
        <label class="btn btn-info btn-small active" for="Languages_2">Inglese</label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="4" id="Languages_3" name="Languages"  />
        <label class="btn btn-info btn-small " for="Languages_3">Spagnolo</label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="5" id="Languages_4" name="Languages"  />
        <label class="btn btn-info btn-small " for="Languages_4">Tedesco</label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="6" id="Languages_5" name="Languages"  />
        <label class="btn btn-info btn-small " for="Languages_5">Portoghese</label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="7" id="Languages_6" name="Languages"  />
        <label class="btn btn-info btn-small " for="Languages_6">Bulgaro</label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="8" id="Languages_7" name="Languages"  />
        <label class="btn btn-info btn-small " for="Languages_7">Lettone</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried to put span3 everywhere but it seems to work only in IE.
You can see the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vandalo/ArUuV/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to break up each group of three checkboxes/labels and put them in their own `div` with the class name `controls`.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="control-group">
        <p class="pull-left">
            <label class="control-label" for="Languages">Lingue</label>
        </p>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-horizontal" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="Languages_0" name="Languages" checked
                />
                <label class="btn btn-info btn-small active" for="Languages_0">Italiano</label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="Languages_1" name="Languages"
                checked />
                <label class="btn btn-info btn-small active" for="Languages_1">Francese</label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="3" id="Languages_2" name="Languages"
                checked />
                <label class="btn btn-info btn-small active" for="Languages_2">Inglese</label>/></div>
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-horizontal" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" value="4" id="Languages_3" name="Languages" />
                <label class="btn btn-info btn-small " for="Languages_3">Spagnolo</label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="5" id="Languages_4" name="Languages"
                />
                <label class="btn btn-info btn-small " for="Languages_4">Tedesco</label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="6" id="Languages_5" name="Languages"
                />
                <label class="btn btn-info btn-small " for="Languages_5">Portoghese</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-horizontal" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" value="7" id="Languages_6" name="Languages" />
                <label class="btn btn-info btn-small " for="Languages_6">Bulgaro</label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="8" id="Languages_7" name="Languages"
                />
                <label class="btn btn-info btn-small " for="Languages_7">Lettone</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here's a working example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htmled/erD9T/).